Approximating the integral of $\arctan(p(x))$
I am interested in methods to estimate the integral
$$\int_0^1\arctan(p(x))\text{d}x$$
where $p(x)$ is a generic polynomial in $x$.
The motive behind this question is the following problem I encountered:

Find an estimate for $a\in(0,+\infty)$ such that
$$\int_0^1\arctan\left(\frac{x^3+x+1}{a}\right)\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{e}$$

My first useful attempt was done simply by using desmos, which resulted in the estimate $a\simeq0.70989$. However, it is a tedious and difficult process to do, and the result could be more precise.
So I searched for a strategy to approximate the integrand, for example truncating a series expansion of $\arctan(p(x))$, integrating, and then numerically find $a$, but faced two problems:

the convergence: the series either didn't converge or converge very slowly.

the series are often made of terms like $(p(x))^n$, which in general are not easy to integrate.


So, my question is: are there other ways to make this process easier in general? What about that specific case?

You can get a quick bound from Jensen's inequality: $\arctan$ is concave down, so this integral is less than $\arctan \left ( \int_0^1 \frac{x^3+x+1}{a} dx \right ) = \arctan \left ( \frac{7}{4} a \right )$. That is $\pi/e$ when $a=\frac{4}{7} \tan(\pi/e) $ which is slightly less than $1.3$. Now the integral is a decreasing function of $a$ and at this value it is lower than you want, so $a<1.3$. More trivially, $\pi/e<\pi/2$ so $a>0$. So now you can bisect...your starting interval is 1.3 units long so you're within 0.1 of the desired answer within four bisections.

Numerical integration sounds like it does what you want it to do, since the derivative of $arctan(p(x))$ on $[0,1]$ is easy to bound, and so for a simple quadrature rule the a priori error is easy to bound. So as long as you say the coefficients of $p(x)$ are bounded by a reasonably small constant, you can nicely find a good approximation

updated for the convergence of the process

You asked for methods that can apply to "generic" polynomial $p(x)$, but in the example we have the advantage that $\arctan$ and the specified $p(x) = (x^3 + x + 1)/a$ are monotone increasing on $(0,3/a)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively.  This makes "root finding" more tractable whether using bisection or more sophisticated methods.

@hardmath I ignored this fact whenI asked the question

Done for the cubic

For the simplest problem, you can have quickly an estimate of $a$ since, for $x \in (0,1)$, the best linear approximation of $(x^3+x+1)$ is  $\frac{19 x+8}{10} $.
$$I=\int_0^1 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{19 x+8}{a}\right)\,dx$$
$$I=\frac{5}{19} a \log \left(\frac{4 \left(25 a^2+16\right)}{100 a^2+729}\right)+\frac{27}{19}
   \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{10 a}{27}\right)-\frac{8}{19} \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{5 a}{4}\right)$$ If you do not want to work this transcendental equation (whose solution is $0.703639$), expand it as a series around $a=0$
$$I=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{30}{19} (\log (2)-\log (3))\,a+O\left(a^3\right)$$which gives
$$a=\frac{19 (e-2) \pi }{60\, e \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}=0.648335$$
If you take more terms in the expansion
$$I=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{30}{19}  (\log (2)-\log (3))a+\frac{4375 a^3}{34992}-\frac{17346875a^5}{272097792}+O\left(a^7\right)$$ and use power series reversion, converting the result to decimals
$$a=0.703256$$
Edit
If instead, you prefer
$$(x^3+x+1) \sim  \frac{30 x^2+8 x+21}{20}$$ the integral becomes more complex but expanded around $a=0$  as
$$I=\frac \pi 2 +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\, a^{2n+1}$$
Truncating the above series to $O\left(a^{2p+3}\right)$ and using power series reversion, the convergence is quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & a_{(p)} \\
  0 & 0.65848550 \\
  2 & 0.70681556 \\
  4 & 0.70954538 \\
  6 & 0.70975177 \\
  8 & 0.70976492 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
 \infty & 0.70976604\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Update
There is a formal solution to
$$I=\int_0^1 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x^3+x+1}{a}\right)\,dx$$ As @Yves Doaoust already wrote, the antiderivative write
$$I=x \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x^3+x+1}{a}\right)-\int \frac{a x \left(3x^2+1\right)}{a^2+\left(x^3+x+1\right)^2}\,dx$$
Using a first partial fraction decomposition of the last integrand
$$2\frac{a x \left(3x^2+1\right)}{a^2+\left(x^3+x+1\right)^2}=\frac {2i x+3(a+i) }{x^3+x+(1-ia) }-\frac {2i x-3(a-i)  }{x^3+x+(1+ia) }$$ and each term can again be decomposed in terms of simple fractions using the explicit roots of
$$x^3+x+(1\pm ia)=0$$ which are not as complicated as it could seem. By the end, the last integrand write
$$\frac{a x \left(3x^2+1\right)}{a^2+\left(x^3+x+1\right)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac {A_i}{x-r_i}+\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac {B_i}{x-s_i}$$ Then, the antiderivative and the definite integral after using the bounds.
$$I=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{a}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^3 A_i\,\log \left(1-\frac{1}{r_i}\right)- \sum_{i=1}^3 B_i\,\log \left(1-\frac{1}{s_i}\right)$$
So, we have the analytical function.
Using now a Newton-like method with
$$a_0=\frac{19 (e-2) \pi }{60\, e \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ which has been the very first estimate
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley} & \text{Householder}\\
 0 & 0.648334501569633 & 0.648334501569633 & 0.648334501569633 \\
 1 & 0.708930340767083 & 0.709870641188367 & 0.709891999040595 \\
 2 & 0.709891251637417 & 0.709891495546698 & 0.709891495546699 \\
 3 & 0.709891495546683 & 0.709891495546699 &  \\
 4 & 0.709891495546699 && \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is indeed quick, but not very precise. I'd like to obtain at least 4 decimal digits correct. Any way to improve your strategy? Maybe the cubic can be approximated by an exponential, and that can be integrated as well (inside the arctan)

@Zima. Have a look at the edit

This is much more useful, thank you : )

@Zima. May be you could accept it in order other users see that the approach is not too bad. Cheers :-)

Sure I will, in order to get the question and answer more visibity. However, if another answer to the more general question comes up, I might accept that.

@Zima  I may have somerhing for thé cubic. Let us see
